# Dynamic email notifications based on submitted form values in Solspace Freeform

Tags: plugin-freeform

Let’s say my form contains a `<select>` element named `inquery_type` with the following options:

- General Inquiry
- Reservations
- Other

And let's say that I want to automatically send an email notification *only* if the form is submitted with an `inquiry_type` value of `Reservations`.

Is this possible. And if so, how would I handle this?